# Is this equation a function?

Tags: functions

I was having trouble algebraically verifying that this equation was a function.

$$x^2y - x^2 + 4y = 0.$$

I tried simplifying it like this:

> $$x^2y - x^2 + 4y = 0.$$
>
> $$x^2(y-1) = -4y.$$
>
> $$x^2= \frac{-4y}{y-1}.$$

I don't think thats the best way of representing it so I just plugged in values into the initial equation. I think that it is a function for all real numbers except 0. Is this correct? Was there a better way of demonstrating it?

Comment: An equation is never a function. But an equation (in two variables) may determine one variable as a function of the other. However, the answer may very well depend on which variable you consider to be the independent one. In other words: your question needs more detail/context. In the above you could just as well ask whether the equation determines $y$ as a function of $x$. You have investigated if it determines $x$ as a function of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the equation a function?

> $$x^2y - x^2 + 4y = 0.$$
>
> $$x^2(y-1) = -4y.$$
>
> $$x^2= \frac{-4y}{y-1}.$$
>
> $$x= \pm \sqrt{\frac{4y}{1-y}}.$$

No, the square root is multivalued. For instance,

$$(-4)^2=4^2$$

See [wolfram's plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E2*y-x%5E2%2B4y%3D0+solve+for+x).

However, if you solve for $y$, we get,

$$y={{x^2} \over {x^2+4}}$$

Which is a function.

Answer (score 0):

$x^2y - x^2 + 4y = 0.$ thus $y(x^2+1)=x^2$ that gives $y=\frac{x^2}{x^2+1}$, for showing that is function Let $x_1=x_2$ then it is obvious that $y_1=y_2$ finished

Comment: My apologies I left out a y in the first part of the equation.

Comment: it is ok, dear. I edit my answer.

Comment: What is this?  I need a more detailed explanation. How is this a proof?

Comment: dear @Zach466920 it is just same as second part of  your answer. I am agree with you that your answer is better.

Comment: I down vote because you purport to have a proof, but in the end it is exactly what my conclusion is except you claim to have proof, which is invalid.